# CryptUnprotectData returns FALSE

Tags: c++

**CryptUnprotectData** returns FALSE, please help me. I try with wstring also, but it returns FALSE too. In which direction to look the error in C++?

```
#include <wtypes.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>
#include "dpapi.h"

#pragma comment(lib, "Crypt32")

int main()
{   
    string in = "fdggddgsgds";
    LPWSTR pDescrOut = NULL;
    DATA_BLOB inData, outData;
    inData.pbData = (BYTE*)in.data();
    inData.cbData = (DWORD)in.size();

    BOOL ok = CryptUnprotectData(&inData, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, &outData);

    if (inData.pbData != NULL)
        LocalFree(inData.pbData);

    if (pDescrOut != NULL)
        LocalFree(pDescrOut);

    if (!ok)
        return NULL;

    char* str = (char*)malloc(outData.cbData + 1);
    memcpy(str, outData.pbData, outData.cbData);
    str[outData.cbData] = '\0';

    if (outData.pbData != NULL)
        LocalFree(outData.pbData);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: `char* str = (char*)malloc(outData.cbData + 1);` - Are you writing C or C++? `malloc` has no place in a C++ program.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Answer (score 0):

```
(BYTE*)&in
```

This does not do what you think it does. `in` is a `std::string`. This results in a pointer to a `std::string`. Which has nothing to do, whatsoever, with the ***contents*** of this `std::string`.

The clear intent here is to obtain a pointer to the ***contents*** of the `std::string`, rather than the `std::string` itself.

To do that, use `(BYTE *)in.data()`, instead. This may or may not be the only problem with the shown code, since it fails to meet Stackoverflow's requirements for [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), however it is an obvious error.

Comment: Why preserve the C-style cast rather than replacing it with the proper C++ cast?

Comment: Was changed to minimal reproducible example. I add **(BYTE *)in.data()** but I get False from **CryptUnprotectData()**.